# Why multiple ptvsd versions are shipped with VS Code?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

Currently When I am installing ms-python extension in VS code. I can see three ptvsd directories 
 a. old_ptvsd    b. new_ptvsd/wheels     c. new_ptvsd/no_wheels

I need following clarifications for debugging(with attach) python script-

Q1.Which is to be used for debugging script which run in another application?
Q2.How long old_ptvsd is going to be supported? As this seems to be stable for both windows and mac.
Q3.When I am trying with new_ptvsd/wheels on windows I could able to import ptvsd and call enable_attach() successfully.But same thing when I am trying on mac it gives following error

```
"nw_path_close_fd Failed to close guarded necp fd 3 [9: Bad file descriptor"
"Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: unable to load the file system codec
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named ‘encodings’"
```

Q4. How I can get which script(like ${file}) is being attached? So that I can run that script in my application?

here is ptvsd server log for Q3

```
    I+00000.313: enable_attach(('127.0.0.1', 9000), './NilLogs', True)

    I+00000.313: Won't trace filenames starting with: [
                     "/Users/username/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2019.11.50794/pythonFiles/lib/python/new_ptvsd/wheels/ptvsd"
                 ]
                 Won't trace filenames ending with: [
                     "ptvsd_launcher.py"
                 ]

    I+00000.313: enable_attach() spawning adapter: ['/Users/username/Repo/MyAppClientDirectory/3P/BUILD_PY/3.6.5/macosx10.6/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/python', '/Users/username/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2019.11.50794/pythonFiles/lib/python/new_ptvsd/wheels/ptvsd/adapter', '--host', '127.0.0.1', '--port', '9000', '--for-enable-attach', '--log-dir', './NilLogs']

    I+00000.456: line 104 : b''

    I+00000.456: line 108 : ''

    E+00000.457: enable_attach() failed:

                 Traceback (most recent call last):
                   File "/Users/username/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2019.11.50794/pythonFiles/lib/python/new_ptvsd/wheels/ptvsd/server/api.py", line 71, in debug
                     return func(start_patterns, end_patterns)
                   File "/Users/username/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2019.11.50794/pythonFiles/lib/python/new_ptvsd/wheels/ptvsd/server/api.py", line 111, in enable_attach
                     connection_details = json.JSONDecoder().decode(line)
                   File "/Users/username/Repo/MyAppClientDirectory/Output/MAC64/Debug/MyApp360.app/Contents/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current/lib/python3.7/json/decoder.py", line 337, in decode
                     obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
                   File "/Users/username/Repo/MyAppClientDirectory/Output/MAC64/Debug/MyApp360.app/Contents/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current/lib/python3.7/json/decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
                     raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
                 json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

                 Stack where logged:
                   File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
                   File "/Users/username/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2019.11.50794/pythonFiles/lib/python/new_ptvsd/wheels/ptvsd/__init__.py", line 81, in enable_attach
                     return api.enable_attach(address, log_dir)
                   File "/Users/username/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2019.11.50794/pythonFiles/lib/python/new_ptvsd/wheels/ptvsd/server/api.py", line 73, in debug
                     raise log.exception("{0}() failed:", func.__name__)
```

Answer (score 0):

All of those versions of ptvsd should be considered implementation details to you; VS Code will select one for you based on an experiment.

As for the `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encodings'` error, that's a sign that your `sys.path` for your installation of Python is probably messed up as `encodings` is the first file Python tries to import at start-up.

But if you truly believe everything should be working you can file an issue at https://github.com/microsoft/ptvsd.